# Usage of "would" and "could" in If clause

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, sequence-of-tenses

I wonder, whether it is grammatically correct to say "it would be great if you could do this for me"? I'm aware of the second conditional's existence, though I don't want to imply the meaning "it is very unlikely you can do this", just ask for a favour very politely. So, here is the list of possible options:

- **(1) It will be great, if you can do this**
- **(2) It would be great, if you can do this**
- **(3) It would be great if you could do this for me**

I, personally,  don't trust that much in the second one, and it seems ungramamtical for me, but I can remember for sure the line from "Lion King" movie (1994) that is: *"I would if you just tell me"* (as a respond to *" Listen, you think you can just show up and tell me how to live my life? You don't even know what I've been through!"*, if it is important), and that confuses me a bit. As for the first one,  I'm pretty much sure that it is correct, but I'm not satisfied with its meaning, because I want to give "more freedom" to the person and emphasize that any choice  is equally acceptable.

So, I will be very glad if someone can comment the grammatical correctness of the last two items.

Any suggestion will be helpful! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.3 is certainly preferable at first glance. Strangely the use of the future tense `will` in your first case is not normal usage, even though we are talking about a future event!

Comment: But  could you make it a bit more clear? My  first variant is ungrammatical or just odd-sounding,  and if so, why? Does this also mean that the second variant sounds normal?